# How to change textView shape and color in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, textview, background-color, shapes

I have looked everywhere to change the textView shape AND color and the only solution I can find is to make a drawable resource file. Which I did:
rounded_blue.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#00BCD4" />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#ffffff" />
    <corners android:radius="30dp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />
</shape>
```

But when I apply it to my textView I get the shape but not the color. The color goes to default.

````
<Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="249dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:text="Login"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_blue"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button_standard"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button_standard"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edittext_password"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.086" />```

[This is what I get ][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5P8Y.png

The edges are rounded as I wanted, but I want to change the button color. Why won't the color translate over as well?T
````

Comment: You say `TextView` but you show a `Button` which is also a `TextView` but is more. See [Styling Your Button](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button#Style) for approaches to change your button's style.

Comment: use `<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>` tag instad of `<Button>` tag

Comment: Whoops. Yes I want to change the button AND textView

Comment: I don't see a _TextView_ in your question. My comment stands for the _Button_however.

Comment: The androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton tag worked! Thanks!